# Unable to get exact circle shape when using card view

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I'm using card view for floating action button in android material design. I'm using following code for get the circle

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:background="@color/blue"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="19dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap = "false"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have set corner radius as half of width. but still I can't get the circle shape.[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Sorry hoomy, i unable to upload screenshot. The card view is looking like rounded rectangle.

Comment: Does it keep the width and height as 38 dp?

Comment: No hoomi, it is not looking like 38dp. looking less than 38dp. actually i tried to increase the circle radius. but it increases the height and width also.

Comment: Hi hoomi, i have attached the screenshot now.

Comment: Have you got answer for this problem?

Comment: No. I did an alternative solution by creating the circle and shadow as an imageview

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Now android providing design library for material design, which has the [FloatingActionButton.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) No need of customizing card view for floating action button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"  />
```

Add design library in gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

For more detail refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/)

Comment: but how can we set dynamic image should be rounded as well

Answer (score 42):

To achieve a circular shape using **Card view** you can set the **shape** property, **android:shape="ring"**.
 **app:cardCornerRadius** should be set to half the width or height of the child view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        app:cardCornerRadius="75dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image" />
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You don't need to add the **shape** attribute as the **cardCornerRadius** is enough.

Answer (score 25):

To get a perfect circle shape using a card view, corner radius should be 1/2 of width or height (taking into consideration that it is a square). also, I have noticed that you are using card_view params, don't.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="38dp"
android:layout_height="38dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="19dp"
app:cardElevation="6dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:background="@color/blue"
>
```

Comment: Not a maintainable or scalable solution

Answer (score 12):

use

> shape = "ring"
>
> use same layout_height and layout_weight

and

> app:cardCornerRadius= half of layout_height or layout_weight

example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/cardview"
                        android:layout_width="110dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:shape="ring"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="55dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 8):

I came up with simple Solution of Using a Drawable and it looks amazing!

Get Drawable here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4Vo_ku-aIKzUFFnUjYxYVRLaGc?resourcekey=0-RiH8lUO0i1kwnZsqquqjnQ&usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Yes it looks amazing this way but then background color can't be changed from white to a desired color since its a PNG and not XML.

Answer (score 8):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="360dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to substantiate your answer.

Comment: iam giving that CardCornerRadius 360dp

Answer (score 6):

I tried your code and found out that the Cards were less round with respect to the increase in the card elevation value.Try setting it to **zero** and this at least makes it look better.

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp";
```

But a probably better option would be to use the `FloatingActionButton` for the round button

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawble_name"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 5):

add this line to the `CardView` which sets the cardCornerRadius to the Circle diameter.

`app:cardCornerRadius="360dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have achieved it by reducing half of the CardCornerRadius to its View's Height.

Answer (score 0):

card_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail_image"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/card_thumbnail_image"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_thumbnail_image);
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rose);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        //Default 
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rose);
    } else {
        //RoundCorners 
        RoundCornersDrawable round = new RoundCornersDrawable(mBitmap,
                getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_default_radius), 0); //or your custom radius

        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false); //it is very important

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            imageView.setBackground(round);
        else
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(round);
    }

RoundCornersDrawable.java

    public class RoundCornersDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final float mCornerRadius;
    private final RectF mRect = new RectF();
    //private final RectF mRectBottomR = new RectF();
    //private final RectF mRectBottomL = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final int mMargin;

    public RoundCornersDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, float cornerRadius, int margin) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mMargin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRect.set(mMargin, mMargin, bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);
        //mRectBottomR.set( (bounds.width() -mMargin) / 2, (bounds.height() -mMargin)/ 2,bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);
       // mRectBottomL.set( 0,  (bounds.height() -mMargin) / 2, (bounds.width() -mMargin)/ 2, bounds.height() - mMargin);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(mRectBottomR, mPaint); //only bottom-right corner not rounded
        //canvas.drawRect(mRectBottomL, mPaint); //only bottom-left corner not rounded

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

first import the [drawbleToolBox](https://github.com/duanhong169/DrawableToolbox) library in your project.
with this library, you can create drawable dynamically.

> for make your cardview circle your radius must be half of its height/widht.

```
                int radius = cardView.getHeight()/2;
                Drawable drawable = new DrawableBuilder()
                    .rectangle()
                    .solidColor(0xffffffff)

                    .topRightRadius(radius) // in pixels
                    .bottomRightRadius(radius)
                     //otherplaces
                    .build();



                holder.cardView.setBackground(drawable);
```

if you are using cardview in your recycleview, getting the cardview widths doesn't work
becuse it doesn't create yet. so you should do as below

```
holder.cardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
         //codes here.
        }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using CardView to obtain circular background with shadow can be quiet troublesome intead use layer-list in drawable to get the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!--shadow color you want-->
            <solid android:color="#C3C1C1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```