# Circular ImageView with SVG as background with padding

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I am trying to set a SVG Icon as the background of an Android ImageView.
The SVG Icon will receive some padding and colors are being changed a little.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="30px"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="524dp" />
```

Is there a way to make the ImageView circular now?
I have tried other solutions but am confused, as they demand me to change the background.

Answer (score 1):

- 1- you can use this library
  https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView
- 2- use cardview
  put imageview inside it and make radius half of width or height
  (as suitable for your use case)    also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584064/6816307)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the imageView circular, because it just displayed the image that already set.

1. Use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library instead
2. Wrap your ImageView with CardView and make the radius half of its width/height
3. Change your image shape to be circle instead